# Extracting the contents of a Google-KML file

Tags: qgis, kml, google-earth

I finally found all the datasets I could possibly need from http://globe.six.nsw.gov.au/ ...but a few hours later I'm not sure if it's possible to access this data into QGIS.

I've tried MapWindow (w/KML2Shapefile), GPSBabel, GlobalMapper and some online tools (as mentioned in other posts); I realise the file is essentially empty and contains a link but I can't seem to 'explore' that link any further.

Comment: https://sdi.nsw.gov.au/nswsdi/catalog/main/home.page has most of that data, and is probably a "better bet" for GIS users.

Comment: @BradHards That's where I've spent the last few days but can't seem to massage the REST / WMS urls to cough up the data - I was just about to pay for it when I noticed the link with KML (which works perfectly in GE) - I'll keep at it then...

Comment: I've had some success with an experimental plugin for QGIS, it seems able to iterate though "sub-layers" of the sixmaps REST service (http://maps.six.nsw.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/sixmaps).

This works on Windows 8.1 + QGIS 2.6.1 (both 32/64 bit). The plugin is provided by Geometalab (https://github.com/geometalab/ArcGISConnector-QGIS-Plugin/tree/master/_release) and beneficial for those who don't know python / command line utils.